# Can't get a button element's onclick event javascript to execute using watir webdriver in headless mode

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, onclick, watir, watir-webdriver

I am using Cucumber and watir-webdriver to write automated tests for my application using a headless browser. I am trying to automate clicking on the **Apply Filter** button below, which runs a javascript function to apply user defined filter criteria to order data in a table.

```html
<button id="apply_filter" style="width: 190px;" onclick="javascript:
                        document.getElementById( 'orderBy' ).value='none';
                        document.getElementById( 'sortOrder' ).value='none';
                        document.getElementById( 'input' ).action='gl_tasks';
                        document.getElementById( 'page' ).value=1;
                        document.getElementById( 'input' ).submit();" type="button">
```

The issue is that the order data in the table does not appear to have been filtered correctly as I don't get the expected order number in the first row of the table. I am confident that the code I am using to set the filters is correct and hence I believe my issue is with executing the javascript attached to the onclick event of the apply_filter button.

Below is the function I have defined to execute the clicking of the button. The commented out code snippets are the alternative solutions I have tried without any success.

```
def apply_filter_button
 b = @browser.div(:id => 'tabs').frame(:id => 'container').div(:id =>'sidebar').button(:id => 'apply_filter')
 puts "Does the Apply Filter button exist"
 puts b.exists?
 b.click
 #b.when_present.click
 #el = @browser.driver.find_element(:id, "apply_filter")
 #@browser.driver.action.click(el).perform
 #b.fire_event "onclick"
end
```

When I use either of the following

```
    b.click
    b.when_present.click
    @browser.driver.action.click(el).perform
```

I get the same result which is incorrect as I am expecting order number 5010064 to be in the first row of the table but instead I get 1636348. This indicates that the set filters have not been applied correctly:

```css
Does the Apply Filter button exist

true

RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected "1636348" to include "5010064"
./features/step_definitions/atom_steps.rb:275:in `/^I should see (\d+) as the order number for line item (\d+)$/'
E:\ATOM_TEST\AcceptanceTest\atom\features\filtering.feature:16:in `And I should see 5010064 as the order number for line item 1'
1 scenario (1 failed)
11 steps (1 failed, 10 passed)
1m33.625s

Process finished with exit code 1
```

When I try to use

```
b.fire_event "onclick"
```

I get the following watir exception:

```css
Does the Apply Filter button exist

true

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: TypeError: Cannot set property [MouseEvent].altKey that has only a getter to false. (injected script#24) (net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError)
[remote server] net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime(ScriptRuntime.java):3629:in `constructError'
[remote server] net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime(ScriptRuntime.java):3613:in `constructError'
[remote server] net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime(ScriptRuntime.java):3634:in `typeError'
[remote server] net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime(ScriptRuntime.java):3656:in `typeError3'
[remote server] com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.SimpleScriptable(SimpleScriptable.java):462:in `isReadOnlySettable'
[remote server] net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject$GetterSlot(ScriptableObject.java):259:in `setValue'
[remote server] net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject(ScriptableObject.java):2796:in `putImpl'
[remote server] net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject(ScriptableObject.java):521:in `put'
[remote server] net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject(ScriptableObject.java):2479:in `putProperty'
[remote server] net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime(ScriptRuntime.java):1574:in `setObjectProp'
[remote server] net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime(ScriptRuntime.java):1569:in `setObjectProp'
[remote server] net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter(Interpreter.java):1253:in `interpretLoop'
[remote server] net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter(Interpreter.java):798:in `interpret'
[remote server] net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction(InterpretedFunction.java):105:in `call'
[remote server] net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory(ContextFactory.java):411:in `doTopCall'
[remote server] com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java):309:in `doTopCall'
[remote server] net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime(ScriptRuntime.java):3057:in `doTopCall'
[remote server] net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction(InterpretedFunction.java):103:in `call'
[remote server] com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$4(JavaScriptEngine.java):630:in `doRun'
[remote server] com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction(JavaScriptEngine.java):690:in `run'
[remote server] net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context(Context.java):620:in `call'
[remote server] net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory(ContextFactory.java):513:in `call'
[remote server] com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine(JavaScriptEngine.java):637:in `callFunction'
[remote server] com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine(JavaScriptEngine.java):612:in `callFunction'
[remote server] com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage(HtmlPage.java):1001:in `executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver(HtmlUnitDriver.java):618:in `executeScript'
[remote server] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl():-2:in `invoke0'
[remote server] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl():-1:in `invoke'
[remote server] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl():-1:in `invoke'
[remote server] java.lang.reflect.Method():-1:in `invoke'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2(EventFiringWebDriver.java):101:in `invoke'
[remote server] $Proxy14():-1:in `executeScript'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver(EventFiringWebDriver.java):213:in `executeScript'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ExecuteScript(ExecuteScript.java):53:in `call'
[remote server] java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync():-1:in `innerRun'
[remote server] java.util.concurrent.FutureTask():-1:in `run'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1(DefaultSession.java):168:in `run'
[remote server] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor():-1:in `runWorker'
[remote server] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker():-1:in `run'
[remote server] java.lang.Thread():-1:in `run'
./features/step_definitions/atom_steps.rb:112:in `apply_filter_button'
./features/step_definitions/atom_steps.rb:267:in `/^I click on the apply filter button$/'
E:\ATOM_TEST\AcceptanceTest\atom\features\filtering.feature:13:in `And I click on the apply filter button'
```

When I run my code using an local instance of an ie browser it runs as expected. I have run out of ideas as to what the issue could be when using a headless browser. It appears javascript is not handled in the same way between a real ie browser and a headless browser. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Note I am using *selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar* for my headless browser.

Comment: I am not familiar with watir but have to suspect this is simply a timing issue. I don't see the line in your code that actually checks the value, but I'm guessing that you have to wait for the filter to actually be applied before checking it

Comment: Hi @SteveCrawford, here are my step definitions as below:

Comment: @SteveCrawford here are the two step definitions in question. The first one calls the function above to activate the apply filter button as follows: `And(/^I click on the apply filter button$/) do
  apply_filter_button
end`. The second one checks the order number column in the table as follows `And /^I should see (\d+) as the order number for line item (\d+)$/ do |order, line_item|
  sleep (10)
  unalloc_cando_task_line_item(line_item.to_i)[1].text.should include order
end`

Comment: @SteveCrawford you will notice that I added a 10s sleep in the second step definition to allow more time for the table to render. Unfotunately I'm still getting the same result. However if I run the tests with a local ie browser instance instead of a headless browser I get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was the following: Needed to change the Apply filter button code so that the references to *document.getElementById( 'input' )* are changed to *document.getElementById( 'task_filter' )*.

That is change:

```js
<button id="apply_filter" style="width: 190px;" onclick="javascript:
                        document.getElementById( 'orderBy' ).value='none';
                        document.getElementById( 'sortOrder' ).value='none';
                        document.getElementById( 'input' ).action='gl_tasks';
                        document.getElementById( 'page' ).value=1;
                        document.getElementById( 'input' ).submit();" type="button">
```

to

```js
<button id="apply_filter" style="width: 190px;" onclick="javascript:
                        document.getElementById( 'orderBy' ).value='none';
                        document.getElementById( 'sortOrder' ).value='none';
                        document.getElementById( 'task_filter' ).action='gl_tasks';
                        document.getElementById( 'page' ).value=1;
                        document.getElementById( 'task_filter' ).submit();" type="button">
```

If you look at the actual html of the actual form it is defined as follows:

```js
<form name="input" id="task_filter" action="gl_tasks" method="post">
```

In our application code which is designed for IE8 we use the value of the name attribute in the document.getElementById(‘input’) call instead of the value of the id attribute. So in IE, document.getElementById(‘input’) will find the correct element, as will document.getElementById(‘task_filter’); however, the correct behaviour should be just the latter. This is what was causing the html unit headless browser to not recognize the form element and therefore not be able to execute the onclick event javascript via the watir-webdriver click commands.

Below is an article which provided us with the hint to resolution: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200802/beware_of_id_and_name_attribute_mixups_when_using_getelementbyid_in_internet_explorer/